# Configure VS2008 to create SQL Server databases instead of SQL Server Express?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008

Probably asked and answered before, but difficult to search for.
In VS2008 when you right-click App_Data folder and create new database, it attempts to create a SQL Server Express database.  Well I have SQL Server 2005 Standard installed and have thus uninstalled Express.  How do I get VS2008 configured to know I want SQL Server databases (NOT Express) created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server Express databases are SQL Server databases and vice-versa. While is true that the SQL Server 2008 database files format is different from SQL Server 2005 one, whthin the same version (2005, 2005 SP1, 2005 SP2, 2008 , 2008 SP1 etc etc) all SKUs (Express, Standard, Exnterprise etc) have *all* the same datbase format.

Yout Visual Studio tools are guiding you down the wrong path. You should not use the Solution Explorer to add a database to the App_Data folder. Instead you should use the Server Explorer tool (menu View/Server xplorer or press Ctrl+W,L) and connect to your SQL Server 2005 instance. Then use the Server Explorer tool to explore the database. To connect to the database from your solution, add a connection string to the web.config file.

While you can manage the database objects from the Server Explorer, thar is a horrible way to do it and will cause only pain on the long run. You should instead create deployment scripts with DDL statements and run those scripts when the solution is deployed. This way your database metadata is part of your source control and you can keep track of application database versions, see [Version Control and your Database](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but you answered a question I did not ask.  Sorry if I was not clear.  To elaborate, I'm looking to change the behavior of VS2008 such that when one tries to add database via right-clicking the app_data folder, it defaults to using SQL Server 2005, instead of defaulting to use SQL Server Express.  (I'm quite well aware how to use Server Explorer.  This is a different issue and question.)

Comment: The add database to app_data is an Express only feature. To develop against the non-express server you have to use the server explorer and such.